# Call constructor from base class - 2 level above

Tags: oop, windev

In WinDev, I have a base class, let say `BaseClass`. This base class has a constructor:

```
PROCEDURE CONSTRUCTOR(param1, param2, param3)
```

I have a first child class that extends the base class, let say `childClass1`. This first child has a constructor with the only 2 firsts arguments:

```
ChildClass1 is a class inherits from BaseClass
...

PROCEDURE CONSTRUCTOR(param1, param2)
Constructor BaseClass(param1, param2, 1)
```

And I would like to have a class that inherits from `ChildClass1` but uses the constructor from `BaseClass`. It seems impossible without redefinning the 3 parameters constructor of `BaseClass` inside the `ChildClass1`.

Here is what I tried to do:

```
ChildClass2 is a class inherits from ChildClass1
...

PROCEDURE CONSTRUCTOR(param1, param2)
Constructor BaseClass(param1, param2, 2)
```

But is says that `BaseClass` is neither a base class or a member of `ChildClass1`.

Does the only solution is to redefine the constructor of `BaseClass` inside `ChildClass1` so that `ChildClass2` can use it?

This seems as a lack of OOP handling.

Cheers,

Answer (score 1):

The explicit constructors of the base class or member must be called in first statement of the constructor of the derived class.
Example:

```
//----Declare the BaseClass1 class
BaseClass1 is Class
BaseClass1Member is int
END
//---- Constructor of BaseClass1
PROCEDURE Constructor(Param1)
Info("Constructor of BaseClass1 => " + Param1)
//----Declare the class named BaseClass2
BaseClass2 is Class
BaseClass2Member is int
END
//---- Constructor of BaseClass2
PROCEDURE Constructor(Param1)
Info("Constructor of BaseClass2 => " + Param1)
//---- Declaration of DerivedClass
DerivedClass is Class
// Inheritance of BaseClass1 whose 
// Constructor expects a parameter
inherits from ClassBase1
// BaseClass2 member whose 
// Constructor expects a parameter
DerivedClassMember is BaseClass2
END
//----Constructor of DerivedClass
PROCEDURE Constructor()
// Explicit call to Constructor
Constructor BaseClass1(10) 
Constructor DerivedClassMember(20)
```